# Implement interface method for different structs only once

Tags: c#, .net-core

Let's not talk about limitation of a struct size, boxing and semantics of having behavior methods in a struct, and just cut to the chase. I have 2 interfaces.

```
public interface IBase 
{
  int X;
  int GetSomeData();
}

public interface IChild : IBase {}
```

Also, I have 3 structs. 2 of them implement `IBase` and 1 implements `IChild`.

```
public struct BaseA : IBase 
{
  public int X;
  public int GetSomeData() => X;
} 

public struct BaseB : IBase 
{
  public int X;
  public int GetSomeData() => X; // Duplicate of BaseA, how to implement this method only? once
} 

public struct BaseC : IChild 
{
  public int X;
  public int GetSomeData() => X * 2; // Child may have its own implementation or pick up the base one
}
```

As you can see, due to absence of inheritance between structs, each instance of a struct has to implement the same interface every time even when the method implementation itself doesn't change. Also, as you can see, implemented method should have access to some internal fields, so it should be able to access `this` pointer. The question is in the code, i.e. **how to implement method only once and use it in all instances, but still be able to use different implementation in the inherited interface?**

Besides obvious answer to use classes that is not an option, here are the others.

**Solution with extensions**

Define common interface method as extension and unique method as a part of the interface.

```
public struct BaseA : IBase 
{
  public int X;
  public int GetSomeDataFromInterface() => X
}

public static BaseExtensions 
{
  public static int GetSomeDataFromExtension(this IBase instance)
  {
    return instance.X;
  }
}
```

**Solution with delegates**

Define common method elsewhere and assign it to the structs that should have the same implementation.

```
public struct BaseA : IBase 
{
  public int X;
  public Func<int> GetSomeData();
}

var baseA = new BaseA
{
  GetSomeData = () => X;
};
```

Mentioned solutions look quite ugly and I was wondering if there is any other way to **prevent duplicating code in structs using the same interface?**

Comment: Code shared between base class and inherited class must be in the base class (not the inherited class).

Comment: Try using an abstract class which will inherit from the IBase interface, then the strucks inherit from the abstract class

Comment: As the OP mentioned 'Besides obvious answer to use classes that is not an option'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with C# 8.0 you can use default implementations in your interface ([see this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods)).
One of the possibilities is to explicitely re-implement a default implementation in an inheriting interface.

So you could write this:

```
public interface IBase 
{
   int X;
   void DoSomething() { Debug.Writeline("Something done");}
}

public interface IChild : IBase
{
   void IBase.DoSomething() { Debug.WriteLine("Something else done");}
}
```

In this case, calling the `DoSomething` method should be done through the base-interface:

```
public struct Base : IBase 
{
    public int X;        
}

var b = new Base();
(b as IBase).DoSomething();  // "Something done"

// or alternatively:
IBase b2 = new Base();
b2.DoSomething(); // "Something done"

public struct Child : IChild 
{
    public int X;        
}

var c = new Child();
(c as IBase).DoSomething();  // "Something else done"

// or alternatively:
IBase c2 = new Child();
c2.DoSomething();
```